# Ajax responseText rendering multiple partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to code a small popup window to add a new event on my app, using ruby on rails and Ajax.

I have implemented Ajax and get the action to works but the string sent within responseText contain more than the partial that I'm trying to display.

Looking at the server side, it makes sense due to the output it shows:

```
Started GET "/events/new.html" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-11 21:58:18 +0100
Processing by EventsController#new as HTML
  Rendering events/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered events/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.erb (223.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 248ms (Views: 244.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

I can see that my server send the new.html from my events controller but then I got an error and some other rendered action. Anyone know why is that so ?

I am adding here the code I have implemented in case that may help

my_app.erb

```
$(".new_event_button").click(function(){
  console.log("click on add new event");
  // $("body").append("</%= escape_javascript(render 'events/new') %>");

  $("body").append("<div class='new_event_window'></div>");

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET","/events/new.html");
  req.send();

  req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(req.readyState);
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
        $(".new_event_window").append(req.responseText);
    }
  }
});
```

events/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Event</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@event, url: create_event_path) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

      <%= f.button :cancel, label: "Cancel", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and finally my event controller events_controller.erb

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with another way like:

use link in views

```
<%= link_to "view", work_path(w), remote: true %>
```

Use respond js on your controller

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
end
```

In view.js.erb

```
$(".new_event_window").html("<%= j(render 'events/new') %>");
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajay  for your answer, I haven't tried your solution, but as it seems easier to implement I should give it try. Thus I am wondering, is this solution also work to create new instance through the REST architecture used by ruby on rails ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController      
  layout false, only: [:new]

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @hoang.vx it worked! I'm still having a rendered error somehow but at least the rest does not come anymore and thus the view is perfect.